# How do I use an SSH public key from a remote machine?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, authentication, public-key

*Setup*
The public keys are set up on a Macbook. I can do a passwordless push to github and a server (iMac) on the local network.

*The Problem*
I know the keys are partially setup correctly, because I everything works if I'm sitting at the Macbook. What doesn't work is when I SSH into the Macbook remotely and attempt to push to github or to the iMac server. I'm prompted to input my SSH key passphrase.

What am I missing to enable pushing to github from the Macbook while logged in remotely from the iMac?

Answer (score 0):

A suitable SSH agent. You can either run an agent on your local machine, load the key into there, and enable SSH agent forwarding, or you can connect to the existing agent during the SSH session. I have no idea how the latter is done.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to upgrade ssh-agent? Or something? Actually, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: If you want to use the agent on your local machine then you need two things. First, you need the agent to be running. OS X already has one, which is integrated with... whatever Apple calls their wallet facility. Second, you need to enable SSH agent forwarding. This is controlled in the SSH client and server configs. The relevant options are `ForwardAgent` and `AllowAgentForwarding` respectively. Once both are in place the SSH client on the remote machine will talk to the agent on the local machine, and you can store the passphrase on the local machine.

Comment: For using the agent on the remote machine, you need to look at the environment variables created by the system on startup, and then you need to set them each time you log in via SSH.

Comment: Thanks. When you say 'local machine' do you mean the machine I'm sitting in front of, or the machine I'm logged into (and attempting to git push) from?

Comment: The local machine is the one you're sitting at. The remote machine is the one you're SSHed into.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a partial solution

```
$> eval `ssh-agent`
$> ssh-add
enter the passphrase here
```

The problem is that this solution isn't persistent as best I can tell. Plus, it appears that I'll be required to enter my passphrase at least once every time I login, which defeats the purpose. I'm not doing a lot of tasks like this, it's always just "login, push, logout".